# Performing operations on nested list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am currently learning python, and I am trying to perform some operations on nested list.
I am trying to square each elements in each sublist and then add them up.
Here is my input:

```
k=[[0.4285714285714286, -0.6428571428571428, 0.2142857142857144],
 [-0.14285714285714324, -0.28571428571428603, 0.4285714285714284]]
```

The expected output is something like this

```
(0.6428571428571428,0.28571428571428586)
```

or

```
0.6428571428571428 0.28571428571428586
```

I tried to use this

```
result=sum(n*n for n in k)
result
```

but got an error that list can't be multiplied by non-int.
I am a bit struggling with the concept of nested list, so I would be very happy if you guys could help me. Also I can't use numpy or any external libraries.
Thank you

Comment: if it was only one list (for ex. [a, b, c]) what is the operation you need to perform ?

Comment: result=[sum(n*n for n in j) for j in k]

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
k=[[0.4285714285714286, -0.6428571428571428, 0.2142857142857144],
 [-0.14285714285714324, -0.28571428571428603, 0.4285714285714284]]
result=[sum(n*n for n in sublist) for sublist in k]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[0.6428571428571428, 0.28571428571428586]
```

**Explanation**

```
k                             - has nested lists (i.e. sublists)
sum(n*n for n in sublist)     - sums of squares over a nested list
for sublist in k              - iterates over each nested list
```

Comment: @Python_learner--glad to help. Not to confuse you but my code consisted of a generator and list comprehension.  A list comprehension only version would be: `result=[sum([n*n for n in sublist]) for sublist in k]`.  If you're not familiar with generators yet, and this is part of a HW exercise then use the list comprehension only version.

Answer (score 1):

using simple map, lambda and list comprehension:

```
k= [[0.4285714285714286, -0.6428571428571428, 0.2142857142857144],
   [-0.14285714285714324, -0.28571428571428603, 0.4285714285714284]]

res = [sum(map(lambda x:x*x, j)) for j in k]
print(res) # output [0.6428571428571428, 0.28571428571428586]
print(*res) # output 0.6428571428571428, 0.28571428571428586
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to know what does 'for n in k' that you wrote do?
basically when you iterate over the list named 'k', you'll get 2 another lists one by one! so in order to have access to the numbers inside them, you should again iterate over these two lists:

your solution could be:

```
print([sum(number ** 2 for number in list) for list in k])
```